# Create HTML GUI with Lua (HTML rendering)

Tags: c++, com, lua, activex, luacom

I'm planning to write a quite complex GUI and potentially change it a lot. My weapon of choice is HTML/CSS. And to handle/control/manipulate it I want to use Lua. The whole thing goes into a C++ project.

The problem is, that I couldn't find an HTML rendering library for Lua.
Have I maybe overlooked something?

If not, I have another idea (which unfortunately would only work under Windows):
Using [luaCOM](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~rcerq/luacom/) it might be possible to access an [ActiveX WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I don't really have an idea how this could be accomplished though... I guess I would have to create a base GUI on the C++ side which holds the ActiveX Control and then I'd have to pass the interface for it to the Lua side?

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with that.

Comment: What are you asking? If you're asking for an HTML renderer, library suggestions are off-topic on SO. If you're asking how to use luaCOM with ActiveX, then that's too broad.

Comment: I'm looking for advice on how to create an HTML GUI that can be controlled using Lua. Tips, links, code, tutorials... I disagree with your last two sentences btw.

Comment: Links and (links to) tutorials are off-topic, because they are off-site resources. Your question boils down to "how do I render HTML using Lua", which requires one of several HTML rendering engines, bindings to them, and code to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wxwidgets toolkit includes [WebView component](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html), which you can access from [wxlua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/). It's cross-platform (Windows, OSX, and Linux). Here is an example of how you can [instantiate the component in wxlua](http://sourceforge.net/p/wxlua/mailman/message/32175734/). You can use a combination of HTML/CSS/JavaScript with some Lua code to generate it, but there are only few ways to get the data *from* WebView to your Lua code.